# What is the best way to store questions with sub questions in database and store students result against those?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-admin, database-schema

I am designing a database to store exam questions and result of students against the exams.

**Question_Meta**: *[exam_id, question_no, question_type, marks]*
I have created this table which will store data of questions

**MultiPart_Question**: *[question_meta_id, part_number, marks]*
But to handle the questions with multiple sub questions, i have created this table which will have a foreign key from **Question_Meta** table and sub question details.

**Exam_Result**: *[exam_id, student_id, question_meta_id, obtained_marks]* 
  To store marks of students on question basis.

**Exam_Result_MultiPart**: *[multipart_question_id, student_id, obtained_marks]*
To store the marks on sub question basis.

Now i have to display the complete exam result in **django admin** but i do not know how can i combine the data from **Exam_Result** and **Exam_Result_MultiPart** tables. Information that is required to be shown on list view page should have columns *Exam, Question No, Sub Question No, Student, Marks*. How can i achieve this in django admin?

Also please guide me if i have used the correct approach in designing database schema? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `Exam_Result_MultiPart` can reference its parent `Exam_Result`, then you may be able to achieve what you're looking for.

```py
class Exam_Result_MultiPart(models.Model):
    # exam_result would be a new field pointing at the parent Exam_Result
    exam_result = models.ForeignKey(Exam_Result)
    multipart_question = models.ForeignKey(MultiPart_Question)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    obtained_marks = models.IntegerField()
```

You may then be able to build a list view around the `Exam_Result_MultiPart`, such as this:

```py
class Exam_Result_MultiPart_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'get_exam',
        'get_question_no',
        'get_sub_question_no',
        'get_student',
        'get_marks'
    )

    def get_exam(self, obj):
        return obj.exam_result.exam
    get_exam.short_description = 'Exam'

    def get_question_no(self, obj):
        return obj.exam_result.question_meta.question_no
    get_question_no.short_description = 'Question No.'

    def get_sub_question_no(self, obj):
        return obj.multipart_question.part_number
    get_sub_question_no.short_description = 'Sub Question No.'

    def get_student(self, obj):
        return obj.student
    get_student.short_description = 'Student'

    def get_marks(self, obj):
        return obj.obtained_marks
    get_marks.short_description = 'Marks'
```

Comment: But problem is how can i make Exam_Result_MultiPart and Exam_Result tables linked to each other? Because for example i have question one with two parts, i should be storing marks of students against those two parts in Exam_Result_MultiPart table not in Exam_Result table. Then how would the two tables be linked to achieve this? Im confused about this

Comment: Also if i introduce a new field i.e. multipart_question = models.ForeignKey(MultiPart_Question) in Exam_Result table to keep sub questions result data in the same table? But the problem is this foreign key field will mostly be having NULL values since few of the questions in exam will have sub questions. What is the better approach? @Will Keeling

Comment: Perhaps it may be better to drop both the "MultiPart" question and result tables? A multipart question is just a question, and will have its own result and mark. Where a question has multiple parts, multiple records could exist in Question_Meta each with a corresponding Exam_Result. Each record could have a value in a "parent" column (new column in Question_Meta) indicating that they belong to the same overall question. Non-multipart questions would have NULL in this column. This might be a simpler approach, given that multipart questions are likely to be few?